# goal time window for dynamic sbpl planner

Tags: ros, sbpl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have a question concerning the new dynamic version of the sbpl planner http://www.ros.org/wiki/sbpl_dynamic_planner.
Is it possible to give the goal a permitted time window?
I want the sbpl to give me only solutions where the robot reaches the goal at a specific time. If this is not possible, how complex would it be to extend the current solution in this direction?
Best
Stefan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10322/goal-time-window-for-dynamic-sbpl-planner/) by [Stefan Stiene](https://answers.ros.org/users/712/stefan-stiene/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently there isn't support for this type of constraint (directly). The planner tries to find a time-minimal collision free path to the goal. However, it would be possible to add this extension to the planner (and I'll do so in the next release).

Until then though an easy hack to get the planner to reach the goal on the interval (t1,t2) would be to put a "fake" dynamic obstacle at the goal location from time 0 to t1 and another fake dynamic obstacle at the goal location from time t2 to some large time. This is essentially how I will implement your feature in the next release anyway.

---

Originally posted by [mphillips](https://answers.ros.org/users/928/mphillips/) with karma: 36 on 2011-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1